# Disable Additional Contextmenu items in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

In Wordpad and other Windows applications, the context menu has [additional items](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/93209-extra-context-menu-entries-ime-related.html) that I do not want (as they make the context menu very large and they are unnecessery). Specifically I do have some CEdit boxes (c++ MFC application).
Since I do not want the additional items, I am searching for a way to not show them at all, thus making the context menu smaller.

I did only find out about ways to disable these on my computer (such as modifying the registry), however I do not want anyone who uses my application to see them.

Basically I am searching for a MFC / C++ solution to solve this.

Comment: Are you asking how to modify the context menu for an edit box?

Comment: Why is this a problem? If your app works overseas, some users will need these options.

Comment: It is a problem as my app will not need this options (wont be used overseas)it just makes the context menu really big, which is not crucial in any way but just ugly

Answer (score 0):

you can override the [CWnd::OnContextMenu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/a8ak6d0a.aspx) on your classes and then you will have full control over the context menu, being also able to NOT show a context menu at all for that given class.

Comment: You make it sound, like you could walk in and modify an existing context menu. This is not the case. Overriding `CWnd::OnContextMenu` puts the entire burden of creating a context menu on you.

Comment: This was exactly my fear, at this point coding an entire context menu is just not worth it